# How to make your program copy itself into another folder?

Tags: c

I know this sounds like a dumb question, but I'm new to programming and I just want to place my program into the start up folder whenever someone runs it.

For example: *End user runs my application* --> My application copies itself into their start up folder (or moves itself)

I'm using C to write this application, and it would be great if you guys can refer me to a function that will allow me to do this (preferably a WinAPI function, but it doesn't really matter).

Thank you, all help is appreciated.

Comment: No dumb questions (most of the time)

Comment: Is this a request for help writing malware?

Comment: @R.. - That's a good question.  I doubt though that the only person who could possibly answer that, will.  I have written services that do similar things, but they are not malware.  Now, let me ask a dumb question - What causes you to assume that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably write the essential parts of this into a separate function, but here are the basics:
***Using Windows*** (per WinAPI reference in post)...

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main(void)
{
  char filename[ MAX_PATH ];
  char newLocation[]="C:\\enterstartupdirhere";//put actual path here (i.e. don't use as is)
  BOOL stats=0;
  DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameA( NULL, filename, MAX_PATH );
  if (size)
    CopyFile(filename, newLocation, stats);
  else
   printf("Could not find EXE file name.\n");
  return 0;
}
```